# R Merge two Dataframes

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
install.packages("XML")
library(XML)

feed <- "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rss"
data1 <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlParse(feed)["/rss/channel/item"])

feed <- "http://www.usnews.com/rss/news"
data2 <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlParse(feed)["/rss/channel/item"])

bigdata <- merge(data1, data2, by = 'title', all = T)

print(bigdata)
```

I am really only interested in the `title` column anyway.  How can I merge just that column from both dataframes?

Comment: Are you sure merge is what you want to do?  What do you want your final output to be?  It looks like none of the titles match, hence no merging.  Perhaps you're looking for `rbind`?  Also, if merge is what you want, I would suggest converting title to character before merging with a line like this `data1$title <- as.character(data1$title)`.  As it stands, the title column is being read in as factors, which can get sloppy for string matching.

Comment: Actually, I solved it by adding `all = T` like `bigdata <- merge(data1, data2, by = 'title', all = T)`.  However, I still don't know how to just merge the `title` column, skipping all the other stuff.  But, maybe `rbind` is better?  All I am trying to do is combine the data from both datasets.

Comment: I think you are looking for `rbind(data1,data2)` ( us news + world news)

Comment: If all you want is the title from both `feed` objects, do `titles <- c(data1$title, data2$title)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all news'title:

```
union(data1$title,data2$title)
```

Also, better to set `stringsAsFactors` as FALSE to get rid of factors: :

```
 data1 <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlParse(feed)["/rss/channel/item"],
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```